# I have a Question regarding that what is view in inside the Widget section

Tags: android

I am curious to know the use of view Widget in android, Which I see often in widget pallet but don't know how to use this, or what is the use of it...

I search it on everyWhere but not find any video or blog, all I find is all the ButtonView, textView, Edittext etc.

I have attach the image please see which view I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: Maybe these links will help you: [link 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) , [link 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-view-and-viewgroup-in-android/)

Comment: It can be useful when you just need a spacer that do nothing other than just occupying some space.